# How can I render the current controller and action name in the view of Play Framework 2?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I would like to render the name of the current action and controller in the view of a Play 2 Application. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried using the stacktrace?

Answer (score 3):

In Scala, we use the following function for this purpose:

```
def actionFromRequest(request: RequestHeader): String = {
    request.tags.get(Routes.ROUTE_CONTROLLER).flatMap {
      c => request.tags.get(Routes.ROUTE_ACTION_METHOD).map {
        a => c + "." + a
     }
   }.getOrElse("ActionControllerCannotBeRetrieved")
}
```

Output here is "ControllerName.ActionName". While you have implicit request in your action, you just simply can include this function.

Comment: This looks promising!